# Find out jQuery selector used in the function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Using jQuery, how to find out easily in a function (*here `myFct`*) what selector has been used to get element (*here `.foo` or `.bar`*)?

```
$.fn.myFct = function(){
 //print '.foo' OR '.bar'
}


$('.foo').myFct();
$('.bar').myFct();
```

Update :
 Sometime the element are called using `#thisisanid`, sometime `.thisisaclass`, or even `div p span`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code from lower jQuery version (e.g. 1.12.4) to achieve what you want in an easy way by using `.selector`
Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$.fn.myFct = function() {
    console.log($(this).selector);
}


$('.foo').myFct();
$('#bar').myFct();
$('div p span').myFct();
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="foo"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
<div><p><span></span></p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function, `this` holds the element itself or an array of elements if called upon multiple.

You could therefore use the built in `className` property to determine which element it was called on inside the function.

```js
$.fn.myFct = function() {
  // Called on multiple elements
  if (this.length) {
    $(this).each(function() {
      console.log(this.className);
    });  
  } 
  // Called on a single element
  else {
    console.log(this.className);
  }
}

$('.foo').myFct();       // foo
$('.bar').myFct();       // bar
$('.foo, .bar').myFct(); // foo & bar
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
```

Comment: It answers totally the question. Now imagine that sometime, the element are called using #thisisanid, sometime .thisisaclass , or even 'div p span' .